# How do I add .jar files on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, jsoup, android-gradle-plugin

I have moved from **Eclipse** to **Android Studio** for android programming.
I am having trouble importing my .jar files in **Android Studio**.
I cannot seem to import any files from my jsoup package.

```
Error:(6, 17) error: package org.jsoup does not exist
Error:(7, 23) error: package org.jsoup.nodes does not exist
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: This has been asked a million times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following in the build gradle file in the dependencies part:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

the above assumes that the library is inside the `libs` folder of your project.

Alternatively you could also add the dependency like this by telling gradle a single jar file:

```
compile files('libs/yourlibrary.jar')
```

After having added this lines you should sync your project again and android studio should allow you now to import those classes from your library.

**Update**: Actually the jsoup library is available in the mavenCentral repository. So a nice way to include this dependency is:

```
 compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2'
```

or just do this to always take the latest version:

```
 compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:+'
```

Note: you need to have mavenCentral repository added in the build grade if you do it like this:

```
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
```

Comment: Thanks..  pasted the jar file in lib in my app and then add it on the graddle built

Answer (score 1):

compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:+'

// worked for me.